# Add business days in start date then subtract 1 business day (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My count of business days in end date should be, for example, May 30 to May 31 will be 2 days and May 30 to May 30 is already counted as 1 day. My problem with `WORKDAY` is that it counts the day from May 30 to May 31 as 1 day only.

What I've think of is to subtract the result of `WORKDAY` with 1 business day to get my desired result. However, with my current formula, I was only able to subtract the result of `WORKDAY` without concerning the weekends (=WORKDAY(C2,B2-1)).

So for example, column C is June 3 (Friday) and column B is 2. The output of my formula will be June 5 (Sunday) because of the subtraction, I want it to be June 6. How will I do that?

Column B = Duration

Column C = Start Date

Column D = End Date (Formula-based)

Column D:

=WORKDAY(C2,B2-1)

Provide Input

```
   B    |     C      |      D   
   2    | 2016/06/03 |
```

Desired outcome

```
   B    |     C      |      D   
   2    | 2016/06/03 |  2016/06/06
```

Comment: I used you formula the way you have it and it returns 2016/6/6 for me.  `=WORKDAY(C2,B2-1)` was in D2, 16/06/03 was in C2 and 2 was in B2

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(C2,B2-1,1)
```

This will set sat. and sun. as offdays

Comment: With WORKDAY Function, it does not have that option. With WORKDAY.INTL Function, "1" stands for Sat. And Sun. as weekend. "2" stands for Sun. and Mon. as weekend. and so on... I don't understand why it was messing up the result, but I'm glad it's working after removing it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear exactly what you want to do.

If you want to do an inclusive count of Workdays from 2016/06/03 to 2016/06/06 then you could just use the `NETWORKDAYS` function.

If you want to add two workdays to Jun 3, and have Jun 3 count as the first day, to give you the result of Jun 6, then use

```
=WORKDAY(C2-1,B2)
```

That takes care of the issue where C2 is not a workday, **and** you want to count 1 workday as the first workday after C2

Otherwise, your formula should work as written.